# Condense list of nested tuples

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I have an assignment that I have successfully solved using defaultdict(list).

In a nutshell, take two pairs of points (Ax, Ay) and (Bx, By) and compute the slope.

Then combine all points that have the same slope together.

Using defaultdict(list) I did this:

```
dic = defaultdict(list)
for elem in result:
    x1 = elem[0][0]
    y1 = elem[0][1]
    x2 = elem[1][0]
    y2 = elem[1][1]
    si = slope_intercept(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    temp = defaultdict(list)
    temp[si].append(elem)
    FullMergeDict(dic, temp)
    temp.clear()
```

Works perfectly. (Yes, there's a lot more to the whole program not shown.)

However, I am being told to discard defaultdict(list) and that I must use a nested tuple based structure.

I have a list of tuples where the structure looks like: (((1, 2), 3), (2, 5))

```
(1, 2) is the first coordinate point
3 is the computed slope
(2, 5) is the second coordinate point
```

NOTE: These are just made up values to illustrate structure.  The points almost certainly will not
generate the shown slopes.

If I start with this:

```
start = [(((1, 2), 3), (2, 5)), (((4, 5), 2), (3, 7)), (((2, 4), 1), (8, 9)), (((1, 2), 3), (4, 8))]
```

I need to end up with this:

```
end = [((1, 2), (2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 8)), ((4, 5), (3, 7)), ((2, 4), (8, 9))]
```

For every unique slope, I need a tuple of all the coordinates that share that same slope.
In the above example, the first and last tuples shared the same slope, 3, so all pairs of coordinates
with slope 3 are combined into one tuple.  Yes I realize that (1, 2) is represented twice in my example.  If there was another set of coordinates with slope 3, then the first tuple would contain
those additional coordinates, including duplicates. Note the embedded slope from 'start' is discarded.

defaultdict(list) made this quite straightforward.  I made the key the slope and then merged the values (coordinates).

I can't seem to work through how to transform 'start' into 'end' using this required structure.

Comment: Please provide some additional details.  How many points are we dealing with (100, 1000, 10000, etc)?  Based on your description, I believe the input is a list of tuple pairs, where each pair identifies a point and where the first & second points are used to compute a slope, the third & fourth points are used to compute a slope.  Is this assumption correct?  Finally, as output do you want a list of tuples where each tuple contains the tuple pairs with the same slope?

Comment: @itprorh66, The number of points is unknown.  We are given two files to test with. One file has 10 pairs, the other 100. What they check with is unknown. The tuples contain two points and the slope computed (using a different function) from those points. You do not need to compute anything. Each tuple contains point A, point B, and the slope computed from those points.  I need to combine all points in all tuples that share the same slope.  Output should be tuples of coordinate pairs who all share the same slope.

Comment: A dictionary is the best way to do this. If it is acceptable, you can convert your result defaultdict to the tuple structure you want by iterating over its `.values()`. If not, the best alternative I can think of is to make a list of lists to contain your points, and a lookup dict to keep track of which index in this list-of-lists corresponds to each value of slope. If you're not allowed to use dicts at all, then replace the lookup dict with a list containing the values of the slope, and use `.index(slope)`

Comment: @itprorh66, FYI the files only contain the coordinate points.  I have to compute the slope and create that tuple structure.  That structure is required, unfortunately.

Comment: @Pranav, That's why I used defaultdict(list). My hands are tied.  I must use the structure detailed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I must use the structure detailed above". You have `start`, you want `end`, so at some point there is a change to the structure. Do you mean that you are not allowed to use a dictionary or a list at all? How does your instructor expect that you go from `start` to `end` without using anything else? Here's an approach that uses only tuples (and the `start` and `end` lists).

`end` will be a list of tuples. We'll keep track of the slope in the a separate list. Expect `end` and `lookup` to look like so:

```
lookup = [   slope_1,                       , slope_2,                   ...]
end =    [((p1_x, p1_y), (p2_x, p2_y), ...), ((p10_x, p10_y), (p11_x, p11_y)), ...]
```

```
start = [(((1, 2), 3), (2, 5)), (((4, 5), 2), (3, 7)), (((2, 4), 1), (8, 9)), (((1, 2), 3), (4, 8))]
end = []
lookup = []

def find_tuple_index_with_slope(needle_slope):
    for index, item in enumerate(lookup):
        if item == needle_slope:
            return index
    return None

for item in start:
    p1 = item[0][0]
    slope = item[0][1]
    p2 = item[1]

    # Check if end already contains this slope
    slope_index = find_tuple_index_with_slope(slope)
    if slope_index is None:
        # If it doesn't exist, add an item to end
        end.append(p1, p2))
        # And add the slope to lookup
        lookup.append(slope)

    else:
        # If it exists, append the new points to the existing value and
        # reassign it to the correct index of end
        end[slope_index] = (*end[slope_index], p1, p2)
```

Now, we have `end` looking like so:

```
[((1, 2), (2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 8)), ((4, 5), (3, 7)), ((2, 4), (8, 9))]
```

The reason this approach isn't great is the function `find_tuple_index_with_slope()` needs to iterate over all the elements in `end` to look up the correct one to append to. This increases the time complexity of the code, when you could use a dictionary to do this lookup and it would be much faster, especially if you have lots of points and lots of distinct values of slope.

---

A better way: replace the lookup function with a new dictionary, where the keys are the values of slope, and the values are the indices in `end` where the corresponding tuple is stored.

```
lookup = dict()
end = []
for item in start:
    p1 = item[0][0]
    slope = item[0][1]
    p2 = item[1]
    
    # Find the index of the tuple for `slope` using the lookup
    slope_index = lookup.get(slope, None)
    if slope_index is None:
        # If it doesn't exist, add an item to end 
        end.append((p1, p2))
        # And add that index to lookup
        lookup[slope] = len(end) - 1
    else:
        end[slope_index] = (*end[slope_index], p1, p2)
```

The code looks *almost* the same as before, but looking up using a dictionary instead of a list is what saves you time.

Comment: As I previously stated, I have the whole program working but I utilized defaultdict(list) in my approach.  The automated grader has assert statements that are checking the structure along the way to the final output.  If all it did was check the output, then my solution using defaultdict(list) would have been good enough.  I appreciate your time and effort.